# drag href from IE to desktop

Tags: internet-explorer, drag

I have two `<a>` tags , with different HREFs:

```
<a href="http:\\test.com">http<a>

<a href="test:\\test.test">test<a>
```

The first one can be dragged out from IE to desktop , while the second one not.

What is the way to solve it?

explorer - IE8

Thanks.

Comment: please specify what version(s) of IE you are testing with?

Comment: Is `test` a registered protocol on your system? What purpose does it have? Why do you need to be able to do drag&drop for these kinds of URLs?

Comment: test is a custom protocol , not registered .What I need is to be able to drag such shortcut to winform app .

Comment: @Ostap - yes, but still..... why? If the protocol isn't registered, then what is it for? (the whole point of a protocol prefix on a URL is so that the computer knows what application to use to open that protocol; without that knowledge, there's no point, and the computer won't be able to open it, and thus won't want to create a desktop icon.

Comment: @Ostap - by the way, protocol references should use forward slashes, not backslashes as you've used in the question.

Answer (score 2):

When you drag a link from the browser to the desktop, the desktop doesn't just get a link added to it; the process is more complex than that.

The operating system recognises looks at the dragged item, and decides what kind of desktop item to create based on the content of the item being dragged.

It is explicitly programmed to recognise the `http://` as a protocol for a web hyperlink that opens in the browser, and thus is it knows that the appropriate kind of desktop object for that is a shortcut icon that loads the browser and passes it the specified URL.

Other kinds of protocol may also be inbuilt into the operating system which would create different kinds of icons when they're dropped onto the desktop.

Obviously `test://` protocol is not going to be one of those that the operating system knows about; it won't know what kind of desktop icon to create when it sees it, so it can't create anything.

In this sense, URL protocols are treated in a very similar way to mime types and file extensions by the computer; they are all used to determine what type of file it is and thus what to do with it.

All this is configurable. If you know what you're doing you can add additional protocols to the operating system, and define how the computer should behave when it sees them. This action is generally not done by the end user though; it is typically performed behind the scenes when you install software that uses that file type or protocol.

Comment: Thanks for your answer . How can I add custom protocol to  operating system ?

Comment: @Ostap - Control Panel / Programs / Default Programs / Set Associations. This deals with file extensions and protocols. Be very careful with it: you will break things if you make edits in this area without knowing what you're doing.

Comment: I tried to do what you suggested ( windows 7 ) . i tried to associate "test" with e.g. notepad ( at least for test ) but with it did not worked . is there is some exact guide how to do it  ? or what I should add to registry in order to be able drag a href like "test://blabla.com" out of IE 8  ?

Comment: Honestly, I've not tried messing with this kind of thing manually for a very long time. There probably are tutorials out there, but I can't point you to one that you wouldn't find on Google anyway.

Comment: I found one :http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767914(v=vs.85).aspx , but still I cant drag the href. may be it is not enough to register the protocol ?

Comment: +1 for the in-depth explanation. However, it is possible that dragging will never be possible for protocols other than http://, registered or not.